# IllegalArgumentException: connection is null, when binding service

Tags: android, android-service

I am using a tab host that I got from github for my project and it has recently broke. This only happens when I load the tab that has my google map in it and works fine for all the other tabs. I get the error IllegalArgumentException: connection is null when calling

```
// Bind the location service
Intent testIntent = new Intent(this, wd_locationService.class);
bindService(testIntent, myConnection, Context.BIND_AUTO_CREATE);
```

Here is the stack trace:

```
08-21 17:25:48.524: E/AndroidRuntime(20354): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
08-21 17:25:48.524: E/AndroidRuntime(20354): java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity    ComponentInfo{com.backtrailtech.hunterelite/com.backtrailtech.hunterelite.wd_mapView}: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: connection is null
08-21 17:25:48.524: E/AndroidRuntime(20354):    at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2180)
08-21 17:25:48.524: E/AndroidRuntime(20354):    at android.app.ActivityThread.startActivityNow(ActivityThread.java:2023)
08-21 17:25:48.524: E/AndroidRuntime(20354):    at android.app.LocalActivityManager.moveToState(LocalActivityManager.java:135)
08-21 17:25:48.524: E/AndroidRuntime(20354):    at android.app.LocalActivityManager.startActivity(LocalActivityManager.java:347)
08-21 17:25:48.524: E/AndroidRuntime(20354):    at com.backtrailtech.hunterelite.ScrollableTabActivity.startGroupActivity(ScrollableTabActivity.java:288)
08-21 17:25:48.524: E/AndroidRuntime(20354):    at com.backtrailtech.hunterelite.ScrollableTabActivity.onCheckedChanged(ScrollableTabActivity.java:272)
08-21 17:25:48.524: E/AndroidRuntime(20354):    at android.widget.RadioGroup.setCheckedId(RadioGroup.java:174)
08-21 17:25:48.524: E/AndroidRuntime(20354):    at android.widget.RadioGroup.access$600(RadioGroup.java:54)
08-21 17:25:48.524: E/AndroidRuntime(20354):    at android.widget.RadioGroup$CheckedStateTracker.onCheckedChanged(RadioGroup.java:358)
08-21 17:25:48.524: E/AndroidRuntime(20354):    at android.widget.CompoundButton.setChecked(CompoundButton.java:129)
08-21 17:25:48.524: E/AndroidRuntime(20354):    at android.widget.CompoundButton.toggle(CompoundButton.java:87)
08-21 17:25:48.524: E/AndroidRuntime(20354):    at android.widget.RadioButton.toggle(RadioButton.java:76)
08-21 17:25:48.524: E/AndroidRuntime(20354):    at android.widget.CompoundButton.performClick(CompoundButton.java:99)
08-21 17:25:48.524: E/AndroidRuntime(20354):    at android.view.View$PerformClick.run(View.java:17355)
08-21 17:25:48.524: E/AndroidRuntime(20354):    at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:725)
08-21 17:25:48.524: E/AndroidRuntime(20354):    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:92)
08-21 17:25:48.524: E/AndroidRuntime(20354):    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
08-21 17:25:48.524: E/AndroidRuntime(20354):    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5041)
08-21 17:25:48.524: E/AndroidRuntime(20354):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
08-21 17:25:48.524: E/AndroidRuntime(20354):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)
08-21 17:25:48.524: E/AndroidRuntime(20354):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:793)
08-21 17:25:48.524: E/AndroidRuntime(20354):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:560)
08-21 17:25:48.524: E/AndroidRuntime(20354):    at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
08-21 17:25:48.524: E/AndroidRuntime(20354): Caused by: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: connection is null
08-21 17:25:48.524: E/AndroidRuntime(20354):    at android.app.ContextImpl.bindService(ContextImpl.java:1415)
08-21 17:25:48.524: E/AndroidRuntime(20354):    at android.app.ContextImpl.bindService(ContextImpl.java:1407)
08-21 17:25:48.524: E/AndroidRuntime(20354):    at android.content.ContextWrapper.bindService(ContextWrapper.java:473)
08-21 17:25:48.524: E/AndroidRuntime(20354):    at com.backtrailtech.hunterelite.wd_mapView.onCreate(wd_mapView.java:1007)
08-21 17:25:48.524: E/AndroidRuntime(20354):    at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:5104)
08-21 17:25:48.524: E/AndroidRuntime(20354):    at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1080)
08-21 17:25:48.524: E/AndroidRuntime(20354):    at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2144)
08-21 17:25:48.524: E/AndroidRuntime(20354):    ... 22 more
```

Also, I am only seeing this problem on my Galaxy Nexus 4.2.2 so far and I am not seeing on an emulator. Thanks.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

So it turns out this was caused by a null connection (myConnection) that I was passing to bindService(). This did not cause problems on the emulator running android 2.1 but on my phone which is running android 4.2.2 it did. It seems some of the changes in the newer versions of android cause this issue.

It was fixed by creating a new instance of myConnection instead of just declaring it.

```
myConnection = new ServiceConnection(){

    @Override
    public void onServiceConnected(ComponentName name, IBinder service) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub

    }

    @Override
    public void onServiceDisconnected(ComponentName name) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub

    }
};
```